# Install Python Package From Private Bitbucket Repo

Tags: python-3.x, package, bitbucket, private

I created a Python 3.5 package for work, which is in a private Bitbucket repo and I can easily pull the code and do a "python .\setup.py install" to have it install, but I want to try to eliminate the step of having to pull the code and have multiple copies on my machine and at the same time make it easier for my coworkers to install/update the package. Is it possible to use git bash or cmd (we are all on Windows) to install the package and ask for credentials in the process?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use the https option listed in pip_install.
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#git

Sample Code:

```
pip install git+https://USER_NAME@GIT_URL/PATH_TO_YOUR_REPO.git
```

You can use the url Bitbucket gives you when you request the clone url. Just remember to add the `git+` to it.

Comment: For a specific branch use git+https://USER_NAME@GIT_URL/PATH_TO_YOUR_REPO.git@branch

Comment: Why does there need to be a user?

Answer (score 4):

Bitbucket is now moving to App Passwords and is [deprecating](https://bitbucket.org/blog/deprecating-atlassian-account-password-for-git-and-bitbucket-api-activity) the use of passwords in the clone command.

To install from a private repo with pip use

```
pip install git+https://USER_NAME:APP_PASSWORD@GIT_URL/PATH_TO_YOUR_REPO.git
```

You can create an app_password from following these instructions https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/app-passwords/

Comment: whats an example of what the `GIT_URL` should look like?

Comment: is USER_NAME the name of the account or the name of the app password?