# Python: Approach for working with a git repo package while in develop

Tags: python, git, pip, setup.py, requirements.txt

I have one repository referencing another and need to define the relationship using a git repo requirement, see [Install Python Package From Private Bitbucket Repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38335377/install-python-package-from-private-bitbucket-repo):

`pip install git+https://USER_NAME@GIT_URL/PATH_TO_YOUR_REPO.git@branch`

Now, while working on both repositories locally, I would like the referencing one to use the local copy and not from git.

Normally then you just setup the other project from the referencing project venv, which I know to ways to accomplish:

`pip install -e PATH_TO_PROJECT`

Which results in the following requirement, that depends on you actually commiting to the referenced project:

```
-e git+https://USER_NAME@GIT_URL/PATH_TO_YOUR_REPO.git@LAST_COMMIT_HASH#egg=SETUP_NAME
```

or the following, which is up to date with local changes:

`python PATH_TO_PROJECT/setup.py install develop`

How would you go about switching between requirements? What is the best approach here?

Comment: I don't think you can combine `--editable` and `git+https`  in one requirement. Editable installs are done from local FS only, IIRC.

Comment: @hoefling `-e` and VCS URLs can be combined, no problem, see https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#git. `pip` clones the repo and runs `python setup.py develop` in it.

Comment: @phd you are right, this just works out of the box